# how to get a signed int from an unsigned hex in C++?

Tags: c++, hex, unsigned-integer

I have been trying and searching for hours now but I just don't get how I can get an negative integer from an unsigned hex. I get 24 bit hex numbers and want signed integers.

(to clarify: I get an get a 24 bit number in hexadecimal. Then I read it as an integer and then I want to give it out as a signed integer.)

`0xfffef1` for example should be `-271` but I don't know how to get there.

Looking forward for some advice.

I have tried to invert the 24bit and then add one like you do with binary but I don't really know how to do that either.

Comment: Do you get `0xfffef1` as string input, or what do you mean?

Comment: no as an int sry.

Comment: Search about "two complement"

Comment: thanks i tried but i dont know how to do that in c++. i can only do it by hand

Comment: There is no such thing as "an unsigned hex". A number is a number is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing the 2 complement with the most significant byte should work fine:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {

    int a = 0xfffef1;
    a |= 0xff << 24;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

See the [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa7a3922fa3ee1cd).

Comment: oh thanks so much thats great. But how can i make that it only does it when it is a negative number?

Comment: @GregorHohl Check if the most significant bit of your 24 bit value is `1`.

Comment: if((a<< 24) == 1) like that?

Comment: or how can i just check the value of one bit?

Comment: @GregorHohl More like that: `if((a & 0x800000) > 0)`

Comment: ok now everything works. Thank you so much. i was already freaking out ;)

Comment: @GregorHohl Just read a bit about binary operations and use the calculator program to convert binary to hex and decimal values. It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that the high order bit, in two's complement representation, needs to be set to indicate negativity; and that depends on the integer size.

For example, with a 8-bit integer, a negative value would be:
`1000 1101`

The same number in 16-bit integers is not negative:
`0000 0000 1000 1101`

So you need to perform *sign extension* in order to fill the leading 0's with 1's:
`1111 1111 1000 1101`
`^--`Extending the sign bits.

My suggestion is to read the hex value into an appropriate sized integer, such as int8_t, or int16_t then cast to an `int` type.