# Casting hex number to signed integer

Tags: c++, typecasting-operator

I have been trying to cast a hex number to signed integer. But its not recognizing negative number.

Here is an example. Do I need to sign extend separately instead of casting?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    int64_t input = static_cast<int64_t>(0xf8546);
    
    cout << "Input: " << input << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have no negative number in your code.

Comment: Why do you think `0xf8546` is a negative 64 bit number?

Comment: It's starting with 1 right?

Comment: `0x1` is also starting with a 1 - do you think it's negative?

Comment: `0xf8546` is equal to `1017158`.  A 64 bit signed integer goes up to `9223372036854775808`

Comment: `0xf8546` is equivalent to `0x00000000000f8546`

Comment: Ok got it. So I have to left shift and then right shift to get the sign extension I think.

Comment: @MikeCAT Are you assuming 64bit for that? I miss a `ll` or `ull`for that.

Comment: @Yunnosch Using `ll` is a good point, but I didn't say it is 64bit. It is also equivalent to `0x000000000000000000000000000f8546`.

Comment: @MikeCAT That is what I was aiming for. ;-) I just wanted to help avoiding the misconception that the number of leading zeros influences the width of what compiler interprets....

Comment: In case you were aiming for the number -31418, if you write `0xffffffffffff8546` you will get that.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Huh? `0xffffffffffff8546` is a positive literal, could be an `unsigned long long` (hexadecimal literals are allowed to be `unsigned` types.)

Comment: But it overflows to a negative value when interpreted as a signed 64-bit number.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Prior to C++20 the behaviour of that overflow is undefined.

Comment: I see. Which warnings do I have to turn on for g++ 8.3.0 to tell me that?

Comment: With `-Wsign-conversion` and without using `static_cast`, g++ 8.3.0 tells me that it `changes value from ‘18446744073709520198’ to ‘-31418’`. Unfortunately it doesn't tell that it's not a defined behaviour.

Comment: During initialization, it is implementation defined behavior to overflow before C++20.  During arithmetic, it is UB until C++20.  In C++20 and beyond signed integers are guaranteed two's complement so we know what will happen.

Comment: @mkrieger1: I'm not sure there is such a flag. My favourite undefined conversion is `unsigned ub = -1e0;`

Comment: Does this mean that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962173/how-to-get-a-signed-int-from-an-unsigned-hex-in-c) would actually be a duplicate question, but its answers are wrong because they invoke UB pre-C++20?

Comment: @mkrieger1: `int a = 0xfffef1;` is implementation defined (special case as you are doing an assignment, not arithmetic) if `0xfffef1` is an unsigned type. There are certainly better answers out there than those on that link.

Comment: The cast here is irrelevant. `int64_t input = 0xf8546;` would do exactly the same thing. The issue here is the **conversion** that the initialization does. A cast just tells the compiler to do a conversion. Here, the cast is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such things as negative literals in C++. `0xf8546` is positive. Its type depends on your platform.

If you want a negative hexadecimal number then write

```
-0xf8546
```

This consists of the unary negation operator applied to the literal `0xf8546`, in the same way that `-1` is the unary negation of the literal `1`.